# How to know that string contains all zeros?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a call option in my app but sometimes I am getting phone number is like "000000000" . So at that case I have to disable call option for user.
But how to know that string contains all zeros?
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loop through the string an check for non zero?

Comment: Can you give a small example please?

Comment: uhh maybe remove all zeroes then save it to temp string then compare length?

Comment: If correct phone number contains three zeros then what @Joshua?

Comment: my answer is the same as avi

Comment: thanks @Joshua I am not able to get you sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all 0's with nothing and then check if the string length is zero.

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"000000000";
NSString *testNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"0"
                                                             withString:@""];

if (testNumber.length == 0) {
    // phoneNumber contains all zeroes.
}
else {
    // phoneNumber may be good.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this i think it will be help you out

```
NSString  *stringToBeTested=@"0000000000";
NSString *mobileNumberPattern = @"^0*$";
NSPredicate *mobileNumberPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", mobileNumberPattern];

BOOL matched = [mobileNumberPred evaluateWithObject:stringToBeTested];
if (matched){
    //contain all zero
    NSLog(@"sucess");
}else{

}
```